# How get view inside adapter class that is not in visible part of ListView? - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview

I have `listView` with ringtones

[image: listView]

I need change `play_arrow` image to `stop` image every time when music started or stoped. 
When I click play on one image it become `stop` image and then I click play on other music item image so previous should become `play_arrow` and just clicked one should become `stop`.
The problem is on getting views by position. Everything works great on first 12 music views. And if I try to get view like this `parent.getChildAt(previousListened)` with `previousListened > 12` it returns null.

**EDIT:** add adapter class

```
class SoundListAdapter constructor(
    private var context: Context,
    private val layout: Int,
    private var arrayList: ArrayList<Sound>,
    private val activity: FragmentActivity,
    private val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
) : BaseAdapter() {

    private var selectedPosition = -1
    private var currentListened = -1
    private var previousListened = -1
    private var isPlaying = false
    private var TAG = "SoundListAdapter"
    private val mSendSoundUri: SendSoundUri = activity as SendSoundUri

    interface SendSoundUri {
        fun sendSoundUri(input: String?)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(i: Int): Any {
        return ""
    }

    override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {
        return i.toLong()
    }

    private inner class ViewHolder {
        internal var radioButton: RadioButton? = null
        internal var txtName: TextView? = null
        internal var ivPlay: ImageView? = null
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        val viewHolder: ViewHolder
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = ViewHolder()
            val layoutInflater = context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null)
            viewHolder.txtName = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.sound_name)
            viewHolder.radioButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sound_radiobutton)
            viewHolder.ivPlay = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay) as ImageView

            convertView.tag = viewHolder
        } else {
            viewHolder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        //check the radio button if both position and selectedPosition matches
        viewHolder.radioButton?.isChecked = (position === selectedPosition)
        // TODO add color to checked circle
        //Set the position tag to both radio button and label
        viewHolder.radioButton?.tag = position
        viewHolder.ivPlay?.tag = position
        viewHolder.txtName?.tag = position

        viewHolder.radioButton?.setOnClickListener { v -> itemCheckChanged(v) }

        viewHolder.txtName?.setOnClickListener { v -> itemCheckChanged(v) }

        val music = arrayList[position]

        viewHolder.txtName!!.text = music.title

        // play music
        viewHolder.ivPlay!!.setOnClickListener {
            previousListened = currentListened
            currentListened = it.tag as Int
            // TODO add black square when playing
            Log.d(TAG, "max items: ${parent.childCount}")
            Log.d(TAG, "previousListened: $previousListened")
            if (previousListened != -1 && previousListened == currentListened && mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.reset()
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(music.uri))
                mediaPlayer.prepare()
                mediaPlayer.start()
            }

        }

        return convertView
    }

    private fun getSelectedSound(): Sound? {
        Log.d(TAG, "sending selectedPosition: $selectedPosition")
        if (selectedPosition == -1)
            return null
        return arrayList[selectedPosition]
    }

    private fun itemCheckChanged(v: View) {
        selectedPosition = v.tag as Int
        mSendSoundUri.sendSoundUri(getSelectedSound()?.uri)
        Log.d(TAG, "selectedPosition changed to: $selectedPosition")
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get item view of `ListView` that is outside of visible part in Adapter class?

Comment: Please, share your Adapter file.

Comment: @Ferran just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible to get item view of ListView that is outside of visible part in Adapter class?*

No, you can't. ViewHolder exists only for visible items.

However, in your case, you only need to set your `ImageView` image inside your `getView` function.

```
    if (currentListened == position) {
       // set here your Stop image 
        viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
    } else {
       // set here your Play image
        viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }
```

Then, call `notifyDataSetChanged`

```
    viewHolder.ivPlay!!.setOnClickListener {
        ...
        ...
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

`notifyDataSetChange` will update all visible items.

On the other hand, you don't need to save `position` in `tag` variable. You always know which item is clicked because your `onClick` events are set in `getView` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I set your answer as correct one cause u were right *No, you can't. ViewHolder exists only for visible items.* But if u can help me with changing back `Stop` image to `Play` image in case hen i click on first music and than i click on second one so the first one should become `Play` image and the second `Stop`. Any ideas?

Comment: When you call `notifyDataSertChanged`, all visible views are redesigned. So, the only item that will show the `Stop` image is where currentListened == position. 
Or do you mean, "how to set a new image in an `ImageView`"?

Comment: I need change back `Stop` image to `Play` if i press `Play` button of other music item.

Comment: I know. See my edited answer. Because `getView` function will redraw all items, what you need is done automatically.  Put the code before `viewHolder.ivPlay!!.setOnClickListener`.